# Visual Studio Shortcuts to commented a part of the line, and select a word

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there any keyboard shortcuts for commented a part of the line? when we want all the line will be comment use ctrl+C but when we need just some selection word between a line be commented what can do?

And is there any keyboard shortcut for select a word, assume your cursor is in the middle of the word and want select all the word (attention because the cursor is in the middle you can not use shift+left(or right)) is there any shortcut for this?

or  Is there a keyboard combination to select an entire line?

Comment: Use Ctrl+K, C to comment a line where cursor is placed and Ctrl+K, U to uncomment a line where cursor is placed

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl+W` selects the current word in Visual Studio. If you are in the middle of a word and want to get to either side of it, `Ctrl+Left/Right` works great. So, for commenting a sequence of words to the right and if your cursor is in the middle of the first word, you can use `Ctrl+Left, Ctrl+Shift+Right, Right, Right...` to select all the words you want.

Answer (score 1):

Select a word: **Ctrl-W**

(Un)comment one line out: **Ctrl-K/C** & **Ctrl-K/U**

Selecting a word is even better with Resharper: it allows you to extend your selection.

As for commenting out one word, no shortcuts that I know of.You could however create a [macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wf883kx.aspx) to do that and hotkey it.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, but with [CodeRush Express](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/) from DevExpress you can use the +/- from the numpad to increase  and reduce selection. It offers very useful [tools for refactoring](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2009/06/25/coderush-xpress-for-c-and-visual-basic-2008.aspx#select).

To answer your question, without an extension this is not possible.